# Record a video from a webcam with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, video, video-capture

I have been trying to get this to work for 2 days now and I am desperate. Basically I want to record a video with my webcam using Qt5. I got so far that I can get a widget to display what the webcam is seeing, but for some reason whenever I try to record it with the QMediaRecorder class it doesn't save anything to the outputLocation.

The output file is created but contains 0 bytes. I have tried playing around with the settings for the video codec, but still no luck. I would think that simple code like this would work:

```
    QCamera *camera = new QCamera(QCameraInfo::availableCameras().at(0));
    QCameraViewfinder *viewFinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
    camera->setViewfinder(viewFinder);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(viewFinder);

    recorder = new QMediaRecorder(camera);
    recorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl(QString("/home/user/test.mp4"))); // removed my name

    camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
    camera->start();
    recorder->record();
```

I expected this to be basically it for simple recording to a file. I stopped the recording in the destructor. So, the question is, why is this not working?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked errorString()? Also, why don't you use fromLocalFile?

Comment: It says: Service has not been started, I saw someone check if it was started in a tutorial or so, but I don't know how to fix it if it isn't :/ In the actual code I use a QFileDialog, this is just for testing.

Comment: Can you check the state() method? Does it return stopped state then? Why don't you set the codec, btw?

Comment: It returns StoppedState. I have the codec set in my current code, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Just in case, you put the errorString() for the media record after the recording? Have you also checked the errorString() method on the camera class after the start? Does the official example work for you?

Comment: I did yes. And the errorString() from the camera is empty. What official example would that be?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html#details Nitpick,  but .at(0) is first(), also, do not hard code the home path, but use QDesktopServices.

Comment: That example doesn't seem to work :/ nevermind about the errors, the camera wasn't initialized in time..

Comment: Can you a gstreamer example then? It seems your issue is with the backend.

Comment: In the official example it reports that the error is ResourceError. But nothing is using the webcam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57609/discussion-between-blackwolf123333-and-final-contest).

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a Windows platform this issue is simply because Qt does not support video recording for Windows. Take a look at this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html

A work around is to use this 3rd-party library https://github.com/kibsoft/QtMEL
I hope Qt does something about this soon. Good luck!