# How can i create avi from camera using directshow?

Tags: c++, camera, directshow, avi

I would like to capture video files from a camera. I captured image files from a camera using sample grabber, but I don't know how to capture video files and save it to avi format. When I call `renderstream` function, an error occurs.

Comment: maybe qt help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841760/record-a-video-from-a-webcam-with-qt5

Comment: thank you for your replying.

Comment: but i want to do this in c++ project.

Comment: isn't there a way to do this in c++?

Comment: on windowse : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Media-Foundation-Capture-78504c83  and opencv example http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html

Comment: does this project capture video from camera?

Comment: read them carefully. they guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows SDK 7.x comes with [AMCap Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424) which is a classic sample demonstrating preview and capture capabilities.

> Video capture application.
>
> This sample application demonstrates the following tasks related to
>   audio and video capture:
>
> - Capture to a file
> - Live preview
> - Allocation of the capture file
> - Display of device property pages
> - Device enumeration
> - Stream control

If you have a narrower problem, please post your code to get an advice specific to your problem.

#### Getting Sample Code

- Install [Windows SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442)
- Make sure to install samples
- This sample is installed under the following path: [SDK Root]\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\Capture\AmCap

Comment: Absolutely, see instructions above.